# What's the origin of the idiom "fish for a compliment"

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

I have been searching for the origin of the phrase ["fish for a compliment"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20origin%20%22fish%20for%20a%20compliment%22&sxsrf=AJOqlzXwEzcdzAuHX1uRJzzk3zVf07Q1FQ%3A1674332809334&ei=iUrMY66EFOKFlQeEtZigCw&ved=0ahUKEwju7Nfiv9n8AhXiQuUKHYQaBrQQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%20origin%20%22fish%20for%20a%20compliment%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEOgoIABBHENYEELADOgUIABCABDoGCAAQFhAeOggIABAWEB4QDzoNCAAQFhAeEA8Q8QQQCjoLCAAQBxAeEA8Q8QQ6CAgAEAcQHhAKOggIABAHEB4QDzoECAAQHjoGCAAQHhAPOggIABAIEAcQHjoICAAQBRAHEB46CggAEAUQBxAeEA86BQgAEIYDSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUJsRWOJUYMtdaAFwAXgAgAFqiAGQCJIBBDEwLjKYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), but I couldn't find anything on the internet. Goose egg!

*The Free Dictionary* defines the idiom

> **fish for compliments**
> To attempt to elicit praise from someone, typically by saying negative things about oneself.
>
> - *We know you're a smart kind, Dan. You don't need to fish for compliments by talking about the one C you got.*

Comment: You might find that "fishing for a compliment" gives you a better idea.

Answer (score 6):

OED provides, for the verb *fish*, a number of definitions, this is the relevant one:

> 3.a. To use artifice to obtain a thing, elicit an opinion, etc.
> Const. after, for. **to fish for a compliment**; also absol.

and in the quotations below this definition the earliest usage of *fish* in this sense is dated 1570, and somewhat later

> 1803   *Lett. Miss Riversdale* I. 264   I feared he would think I was
> fishing for a compliment.

Comment: You didn't provide a link, but you seem to be citing [the *full* OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70650?rskey=LHUkeB&result=5#eid). Which is subscription-only - otherwise I'd have voted to close the question for lack of prior research.

Comment: (Why on earth would anyone downvote this answer?)

Comment: Yes, I'm citing the full OED, and yes, I know that it (the online edition which I am quoting from) is subscription only. And no, I haven't read the full Ts and Cs so am relying on 'fair use' and internet-anonymity to avoid Oxford University Press's black helicopters renditioning me to the dungeons below the Bodleian ...

Comment: I assume most people who try to follow the link in  my first comment will hit the paywall (but I *think* the full OED offers unrestricted access on an "unannounced" day about once a month). I seriously doubt OED would take us (or Stack Exchange) to task for reproducing some of their definitions here -- especially if they're *attributed*. But unless we can easily locate the same information *freely* accessible online, we certainly can't expect the OP to find it for himself.

Comment: A link might be useful for those who *do* have a subscription (with an explantory note for non-subscribers).

Comment: But I *have* provided a link ... the word *fish* links to its definition and it will work with any dictionary not just the OED.

Comment: The answer contains **no links** at all to support it, ref the [first comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601862/whats-the-origin-of-the-idiom-fish-for-a-compliment#comment1516769_601863).

Comment: There is **no link** in the *answer*.  I can see the link in FF comment, it appears in red, and it works  but I do not a subscription to the OED so I cannot see the entry. Could you please quote the 1570 example, does it use "fish for compliment(s)".

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I didn't include the 1570 quotation precisely because it doesn't include the expression *fish for compliment(s)*, it uses *fish* in the sense provided, but in a different context.

Comment: Still no link, but thanks anyway for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

A Google Books search turns up several matches for the phrase from the  1700s. From a [letter from J.S.H. to William Shenstone, dated March 16, 1754](https://books.google.com/books?id=lwJEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA201&dq=%22fish+for+a+compliment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9subLoNb_AhW5kIkEHcGbC3sQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fish%20for%20a%20compliment%22&f=false), reprinted in *Select Letters Between the Late Duchess of Somerset, Lady Luxborough, Mr. Whistler, Milss Dolman, Mr. R. Dodsley, William Shenstone, Esq. and Others* volume 1 (1778):

> Am I not so *very* vain to think you can so *very* easily forgive me; I fear you will have more Reason to find Fault with me in the Country, when I shall be so much nearer to you then than I am now. I do not **fish for a Compliment**, when I say, I have many dark Spots for a few white ones: but I flatter myself, you will have the Goodness to bear with my Foibles, more than any body else.

From James Boswell, [*The Life of Samuel Johnson*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RJJNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA429&dq=%22fishing+for+a+compliment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtoKwnNb_AhXDrokEHVLNDW8Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fishing%20for%20a%20compliment%22&f=false), volume 2 (1791):

> Johnson had a general aversion to pun, He once, however, endured one of mine. When we were talking of a numerous company in which he had distinguished himself highly, I said, "Sir, you were a Cod surrounded by smelts. Is not this enough for you? at a time too when you were not ***fishing* for a compliment**?" He laughed at this with a complacent approbation. Old Mr. Sheridan observed, upon my mentioning it to him, "He liked your compliment so well he was willing to take it with *pun sauce*."

From "[Gleanings of Biography: Memorandums of Thomson the Poet and His Associates, Communicated by Mr. Robertson of Richmond in Surrey, Late Surgeon to the Houshold at Kew, October 17th, 1791](https://books.google.com/books?id=uDAoAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA285&dq=%22fifhing+for+a+compliment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG9LKcptb_AhUNjYkEHa93AnMQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false)," in *The Bee, Or, Literary Weekly Intelligencer* (December 28, 1791):

> Q. Then, Sir, I suspect you are the only one who could not make the discovery?—Sir , I was not **fishing for a compliment** I assure you.
>
> A. If you had, Sir, I should not have snatched so eagerly at your bait.

From "[Gray the Poet,—A Dialogue Concerning Youth](https://books.google.com/books?id=6SM2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22fishing+for+a+compliment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtoKwnNb_AhXDrokEHVLNDW8Q6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fishing%20for%20a%20compliment%22&f=false)," in *The Bee: Or Literary Weekly Intelligencer* (October 2, 1793):

> *West.* How delightful is this vernal day and sweet retirement on the banks of the imperial Thames ; ... I imagine Gray, by tuning his pipe to it so often, has been assimulated to it, as we generally are to what we admire.
>
> *Walpole.* Sentimental young rogue : I see what kind of sport you are thinking of on the margin of this river. You are ***fishing* for a compliment** in immortal verse from Gray, when he shall have finished his apprenticeship to the muse on the Thames, and set up in business for him self.

From Miss Hutchinson, [*Exhibitions of the Heart; a Novel*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=chi.45297710&view=1up&seq=69&q1=%22fishing%20for%20compliments%22), volume 3 (1799):

> "It would be a difficult task for me to think so, madam," exclaimed captain Osnaburgh, "especially when I look round this table."---"I swear, Osnaburgh," said Melcourt, "you are grown quite gallant, since I saw you last,” observing whether Matilda's eyes were fixed on the strangers--"you are **fishing for compliments**, I protest," continued Melcourt, who, with all the vivacity of one who laughs at the past and thinks only on the present moment, entertained the company with a thousand sallies of wit and humour ; ...

And from Harriet Pigott, [*Emily Dundorne; or, The Effects of Early Impressions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AqYBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22fishing+for+a+compliment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtoKwnNb_AhXDrokEHVLNDW8Q6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fishing%20for%20a%20compliment%22&f=false), volume 3 (1799):

> The principal accomplishments to be obtained, were dancing and the French language. They should be paid liberally, he said, for their apartments and table: at the same time, that he should be sorry to occupy any apartments that might in any other way bring more to the family: thus **fishing for a compliment** to his fortune.

The upshot of these various examples is that English speakers and writers were using the expression "fish for a compliment" (and its variants) in the same sense in which the expression is used today at least as early 1754, and that its use appears to have become more widespread starting in the 1790s.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite an old idiomatic expression, apparently originated from US campus:

> [fish](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/sbxcwli) *v*.<sup>1</sup>
> [? SE *fish* for compliments]
> **1.** (*US campus*) to toady, to ingratiate oneself.
>
> 1774 T. Hutchinson Diary I 261: *[He courts me a good deal, and fishes](https://books.google.it/books?id=WOUbw0m-1pUC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=%22He%20courts%20me%20a%20good%20deal,%20and%20fishes%22&source=bl&ots=jdC6s_qKkc&sig=ACfU3U1GBXNJP2ufomi6CtRF2ONVPGfN9A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5hOubvdn8AhVVSfEDHTXyBR0Q6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=%22He%20courts%20me%20a%20good%20deal%2C%20and%20fishes%22&f=false)* [DA].
>
> 1795 will of Charle Prentiss in Hall (1856) 200: *I give to those that fish for parts, / Long sleepless nights, and aching hearts.*

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)

<sub>SE: Standard English</sub>

Comment: "apparently originated from US campus"? That's ridiculous!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - see you saying that Green’s Dictionary is a ridiculous source?

Comment: No. I'm saying it's ridiculous to suggest that the usage OP is asking about "originated from US campus". If you got that from Green, you must have misunderstood something. If you provide an actual ***link***, I might look at it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers / please check yourself.

Comment: Green's dictionary seems to be saying that the lone word "fish" in the given sense is a "US campus" usage, but the question is about the longer phrase "fish for compliments," which Green doesn't describe. (For posterity, the notation "[? SE fish for compliments]" seems to mean "etymology: maybe from the standard English 'fish for compliments.'")

Comment: @TannerSwett - sorry the link clearly says: ***(US campus) to toady, to ingratiate oneself.***

Comment: Yes, and the entry clearly says "fish," not "fish for compliments."

Comment: @TannerSwett - fish in the sense  of toady, fish for compliments. See examples below.

Comment: But the question wasn't "What's the origin of the word 'fish' in the sense of 'toady, fish for compliments'"; the question was "What's the origin of the idiom 'fish for a compliment'?" That's a totally different question with a totally different answer.

Comment: @TannerSwett - don’t see your point. The original sense is quite relevant. Not my fault If it comes from US campus.

Comment: @TannerSwett the quotations support the answer, as I understand it, the examples show the figurative and metaphotical meaning  of "fish" when a speaker tricks or baits someone in order to  receive praise.